# jQuery validation required rule not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Ok so I am working on a form that tests specific form element against the validation rules I have set up.  I am trying to set the Boolean variable `hasError` to `true` or `false` based on whether `.valid()` returns `true` or `false`.  The problem I am having is for some reason `.valid()` returns `false` when a user does not enter data into an input even though my rule is set to `required: false`.  Shouldn't setting a rule to `required: false` allow validation to pass even if no data is entered?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
            var check = false;
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
            },
            "Please do not use any special characters"
);

$('#formElem').validate({       
    rules: {
        testItem:{required: false, regex: /^[0-9A-Za-z\s`~!@$%^&*()+{}|;'",.<>\/?\\-]+$/}
            }

        });
var hasError = false;
if($('#testItem').valid()) {
    hasError = false;
}else{
    hasError = true;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a working jsfiddle?

Comment: You should show enough code to duplicate the reported issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Shouldn't setting a rule to `required: false` allow validation to pass even if no data is entered?"*

**Yes, it should, and yes, it absolutely does: http://jsfiddle.net/J2p9N/**

**HTML**:

```
<form id="formElem">
    <input type="text" name="testItem" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formElem').validate({
        rules: {
            testItem: {
                required: false
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Quote OP:**

> *"I am trying to set the Boolean variable `hasError` to `true` or `false` based on whether `.valid()` returns `true` or `false`."*

Are you perhaps getting confused because your code is setting `hasError` to `false` whenever `.valid()` returns `true` and vice-versa?

```
if($('#testItem').valid()) {
    hasError = false;
}else{
    hasError = true;
}
```

Otherwise, something else must be wrong with your code.  You should show enough code to duplicate the reported issue in a jsFiddle.